# Is it possible to not be in @Transaction state, when calling a function from a transacted function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

Not sure how to word the title but I'm using Spring boot, and I have a function like:

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public Optional<List<SomeClass>> bulkInsert(List<SomeClass> models, boolean withRefresh) {
        int rowsInserted = someDao.bulkInsert(models).length;
        if (rowsInserted > 0 && withRefresh) {
            // I don't want the getLatest() function to operate in a transaction
            return Optional.of(getLatest(someValue, models.size())); 
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    };

    @Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<SomeClass> getLatest(long someValue, int limit) {
        TransactionStatus status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(); ### says the transaction is active
        return someDao.getLatest(accountId, limit);
    };
```

Basically I want to exclude the getLatest() from the transaction. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "exclude from transaction"? In your current code as you make the call for "getLatest" internally the  @Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED) is not applied and totally useless.

Comment: I think you already answered what I wanted to know below. I wrapped the insert in a manual transaction, removed @Transactional, and put the getLatest after the transaction completes. All using TransactionTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
 @Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<SomeClass> getLatest(long someValue, int limit) {
```

See [Spring Propagation Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) for explanation of propagation levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use transaction only for

```
someDao.bulkInsert(models).length;
```

then you should wrap this code with transactional aspect and call the other part separately. Like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public int bulkInsert(List<SomeClass> models, boolean withRefresh) {
   return  someDao.bulkInsert(models).length;
}

public Optional<List<SomeClass>> abc(int rowInserted, boolean withRefresh){
    if (rowsInserted > 0 && withRefresh) {
       return Optional.of(getLatest(someValue, models.size())); ### I don't want the getLatest() function to operate in a transaction
    }

    return Optional.empty();
} 

public List<SomeClass> getLatest(long someValue, int limit) {
  TransactionStatus status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(); ### says the transaction is active
  return someDao.getLatest(accountId, limit);
};
```

Most importantly you need to call this method from outside of this instance.

For the question you have in the title: No you can't take some piece of the code outside of the transaction because spring-aop uses proxies and the whole method is wrapped with transactional aspect in the proxy instance.

Comment: Thing is I didn't want to seperate the insert/getLatest from each other, but if I wanted to this would be a good way of doing it. Or just call getLatest from the controller without 'withLatest' even.